# running a method with object from a string

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, cocoa

at one point of my code I have references to methods as strings and I have their targets. For example, suppose I have an object called myObject and I have a method there called "doSomething:" like this:

```
- (void)doSomething:(id)sender {
   // do something baby
}
```

at one point of my code I store references to both object and method doing this:

```
NSString *myMethod = @"doSomething:";
id myTarget = myObject;
```

later, in another point of the code I want to do this

```
[myObject doSomething:self];
```

but how do I reconstruct the method call to that object from an reference id to the object and from a NSString that represents the method and how do I pass self to that method?

thanks

Comment: Hint: You want to create a "selector".

Comment: use `NSSelectorFromString`, check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSSelectorFromString)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For converting a string towards a selector, use `NSSelectorFromString`. For the other way around, use `NSStringFromSelector`.

Convert the selector:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(methodSelectorString);
```

Invoke method:

```
[myObject performSelector:selector withObject:self afterDelay:0.0];
```

---

From the [Foundation reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html);

```
NSSelectorFromString
```

Returns the selector with a given name.

```
SEL NSSelectorFromString (
   NSString *aSelectorName
);
```

Parameters

```
aSelectorName
```

> A string of any length, with any characters, that represents the name
>   of a selector. Return Value The selector named by aSelectorName. If
>   aSelectorName is nil, or cannot be converted to UTF-8 (this should be
>   only due to insufficient memory), returns (SEL)0.
>
> Discussion To make a selector, NSSelectorFromString passes a UTF-8
>   encoded character representation of aSelectorName to sel_registerName
>   and returns the value returned by that function. Note, therefore, that
>   if the selector does not exist it is registered and the
>   newly-registered selector is returned.
>
> Recall that a colon (“:”) is part of a method name; setHeight is not
>   the same as setHeight:. For more about methods names, see “Objects,
>   Classes, and Messaging” in The Objective-C Programming Language.

---

```
NSStringFromSelector
```

Returns a string representation of a given selector.

```
NSString *NSStringFromSelector (
   SEL aSelector
);
```

Comment: so? after converting the string to a selector how do I call the method on that object passing self as an object?

Answer (score 1):

As said by @Till, you need to use `NSSelectorFromString()`.

You can use the following code:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(myMethod);
if(selector)
{
   [myObject performSelector:selector withObject:self];
}
```